# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

I have a problem where I am attempting to return the count of objects in an array that are within 1 standard deviation. In order to get standard deviation, I created two functions, but now I can't add/subtract the functions. I attempted to convert the functions to integers, but began getting an error regarding the fact that my standard deviation is a float. What is a better way to do all of this?

```
import numpy as np
import math
vac_nums=np.array([180, 172, 178, 185, 190, 195, 192, 200, 210, 190])
def variance():
    n = len(vac_nums)
    mean = sum(vac_nums)/n
    deviations = [(x - mean) ** 2 for x in vac_nums]
    variance = sum(deviations)/n
    return variance
print(variance())
def stdev():
    var = variance()
    std_dev = math.sqrt(var)
    return std_dev
print(stdev())
sum = 0 
for x in vac_nums:
    if np.array(x) >=(variance-stdev) and np.array(x) <=(variance+stdev):
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

Comment: Since you're using `numpy` anyway, why not use `std_dev = np.std(vac_nums)`?

Comment: Why would you subtract functions? That makes no sense. Maybe you want to subtract the values that the functions returned instead? `variance() - stdev()`

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `sum`, as that replaces the built-in function that `variance` will use when you call it in the loop.

Comment: Consider that you should provide your printouts and full error traceback from the code to have a [mcve]

Comment: @not_speshal apologies, I should have clarified. I am actually going to input this into sololearn to answer a question where they have already created an array. I can't import on their field. I only imported numpy to add the array in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @CherryDT can you clarify how to do this? I am brand new to this.

Comment: @chepner thanks!

Comment: @Samples I showed it in my comment above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are [first class objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in python, as are integers, lists, classes, and everything else you are likely to imagine on short notice. Functions can be *called*, in which case it returns a *return value*. A function is called with the `()` operator, sometimes containing *arguments*.

You've created two function objects in your code: `variance` and `stdev`. Those two names refer to the function objects.

You call the functions in each of the `print` statements that follow them. For example `variance()` is a call that returns a `float`, which you can print.

The sum of two function objects is meaningless, as you would expect. You can add integers, floats, and even lists meaningfully, but what is the sum of functions? Since the return value of each of the functions is a number, you can add (or subtract) those meaningfully:

```
variance() + stdev()
```

Normally we store the return value of an expensive function call to a variable once and use that variable instead of rerunning all the operations of the function. In python, you store variables by binding an object (like a return value) to a name using the `=` operator. You could do something like this:

```
s = stdev()
print(s)
...
v = variance()
print(v)
...
# Use v + s in an expression instead of variance + stdev
```